# SSIS error message: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: ssis

For a university group project, we are building a data warehouse using SQL Server Management and Visual Studio. We are currently in the staging area and want to fill the tables with data. It works fine for our dimension tables, but it simply doesn't work for our fact table sales. We have tried several different options and now have two final options, both of which should work. The first option can be executed without error messages, but the rows stop being forwarded after "Merge Join".
[image: see image]

With the second option we get an error message in the OLE DB destination [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw4nv.png) as follows:

> [OLE DB Destination [115]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.    > An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.
> Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80004005
> Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_Fact_Sales'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Stg_Fact_Sales'. The duplicate key value is (2021-12-31, 017692475c1c954ff597feda05131d73, 3c7c4a49ec3c6550809089c6a2ca9370, a08ac24c7188aae96f09570ffde66b40, 66188).".

In either way, the fact table is completely empty on SQL.

For a better understanding and insight, we are providing you with our SQL scripts, flat files as well as visual studio data flow: [Download files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N12ScowPfXE-4xdZeEI60xwO97IBx65w/view?usp=sharing)

If anyone can help figure out what our problem is, we would be more than happy!

Thank you very much and all the best!

---

@Jayvee: Thank you very much again for your help! We tried doing what you suggested to us and it worked as well for us!

However, we noticed that the sum of the price + the sum of the freight value is different from the payment_value as well as the values differ from the csv file. That is why we tried to additionally check the box “Remove rows with duplicate sort values” in the Sort 1. Instead of having 117.216 rows in the end, we end up with 102.727 rows. Yet, there is still a variation between all of the values. For a better overview and understanding, please refer to the following image: [image].

Do you know why this might be happening or have a solution to solve this problem?

Also, we tried to move forward with the Reviews fact table. In this table we would like to show the average score (made for orders) for each customer unique id, taking into account the different dates. In other words, one customer can make more than one review on the same day, so we want to do the average for those cases. If the customer made the review on a different day, we do not want to include this information for the calculation of the average. Could you maybe help us how to do this with visual studio? We tried using the Aggregate function, but it did not work out. Can you maybe help here as well? (We don’t care about the relation with the order, we just want to know the average for the scores made by the same customers on the same day.)

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Even if table is empty on SQL, check that the data you are trying to insert doesn't contains duplicates

Comment: As already mentioned, the data you are loading into the fact has a duplicate on whatever primary key you have defined.

Comment: The thing is we checked duplicate values and are sure we don't have any! Also what is weird in the error message, it says 2021-12-21 and we do not have any dates in 2021 in our dataset....

Comment: @Rachel the duplications are due that there could be more than one payment per order, it is a model design issue. Payment should actually be another fact table, separate from sales. Regarding the aggregation, please post it as a new question.

Comment: @Javyee: thank you very much! so basically there is no other way to make sure the values are the same as in the csv file than by creating a payment fact table? We would have payment value on one table - the fact_payment 

and on the fact_sales we would have price+freight value (Price+freight value=payment value)

Does it make sense to have the two numbers on two different tables, given the that they are the same? 

Regarding the aggregation, I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70576457/ssis-average-transformation-for-duplicate-entries

Comment: @Javyee we were trying to create a fact table for payment, however we are not sure how to do it, since we thought it is not possible to have two fact tables connected to each other. Could you maybe help us out here as well, because Payments should be connected to Sales, however Sales is a fact table...

Comment: Conceptually, fact tables are connected to other fact tables via conformed dimensions. Often they are different grain (i.e. days vs months) which can be a challenge for some BI tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually are some transactions that create duplicates keys:

Fact Sales PK is as follows:

```
FK_Date ASC,  
FK_Product ASC,
FK_Sellers ASC,
FK_Customer_unique ASC,
FK_Payment ASC


FK_Date comes from orders file
FK_Product, FK_Sellers and FK_Customer_unique come from order_item file 
FK Payment comes from payment file
```

Now, if we check the files for the product_id that created the PK duplication (cb07b3df7c64648bbeceb85cacd464c9)

in order_items:

[image]

As you can see 2, items with the same product_id, seller_id and order_id

in orders:

[image]

in payments:

[image]

So when the two records from order_item merge with order and payment file (using order_id as join key) you will end up with two records with the same

FK_product (cb07b3df7c64648bbeceb85cacd464c9)
FK_date (23-01-2017)
FK_seller (62c50c1af4dfdc4149d25c5222043d39)
FK_customer_unique (8a0793d04e0f4be13434516ee7037104)
FK_payment (38321)

so that is why you need to either add something to the fact table to make it unique (order_item_id, for instance)
or
ignore the duplicates by removing the records with same sort value in the sort transformation of order items
or
group order_items by order_id summing the freight value

which of the three solutions will depend on the rules of the problem (i.e the meaning of freight value, is it divided between items or it's just repeated?)

hope this helps to clarify the issue

**Suggested Solution**

fact sales table:

```
CREATE TABLE Stg_Fact_Sales (
FK_Date DATE ,
FK_Product NVARCHAR(50) ,
FK_Sellers NVARCHAR(50),
FK_Customer_unique NVARCHAR(50) ,
FK_Payment INT ,
Delays INT NULL,
Price DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
Freight_value DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
Payment_value DECIMAL (18,2) NOT NULL,
Order_status NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Order_id NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Order_item_id NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Fact_Sales PRIMARY KEY (
Order_id ASC,
Order_item_id ASC,
FK_Payment ASC
)
);
```

as you can see, I've added order_id and order_item_id to the table and made these two columns, plus payment number, the composite PK.

Now the package needs to reflect these changes.

Sort 1 now includes order_item_id

[image]

also does Merge Join

[image]

and Merge Join 1

[image]

And finally make sure you map these two new fields to the corresponding columns in OLE DB Destination:

[image]

Result:
All the data loaded without issues:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! We will try this and I will let you know if we could solve it! Thank you so much for your time and effort! We really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, let us know if you get stuck somewhere. if you are happy with the answer(s) please accept/vote them up :)

Comment: In order to add the order_item_id to the fact sales table, we would need to create an order_item dimension table in our script, right?

Comment: We are really confused what to change in the script in order to be able to add order_item_id to the fact sales table...

Comment: Try the second option, in the sort transformation editor (sort 1) tick the box "remove rows with duplicate sort values"

Comment: for the first option,you may need to change the table structure to include order_item_id and also add it to the primary key, then, in the package, bring order_item_id all the way down to the table

Comment: if you still have problems, please upload your latest visual studio package version and tomorrow I'll show with pictures what changes are needed

Comment: That would be really amazing! Thank you so much! The latest version of our visual studio is uploaded here: (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KaFwjjBu9Zf47Rz1XYiWplkam3JW6NIJ?usp=sharing). We would really appreciate it if you could help us with the sum of the price as well as the freight_value in case order_ids are duplicated, because if we delete the duplicates of the order_id, we will lose revenue... --> our best solution is in the LOAD_ Stg_Fact_Sales3

Comment: Sorry I couldn't open the new files, but I worked with the initial ones. See suggested solution. Regarding the sum, I don't think the aggregation before loading to staging area is the best option, actually I think there already are a lot of transforms as it is now, in general, there is not even referential integrity enforcement in the staging area, although this is debatable and depends on the domain case design. But if you want to know how to do this aggregation please post it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you so much! We will try your suggested solution this afternoon and will let you know if it works out! Thank you a lot, we really appreciate your help!

Comment: _The thing is we checked duplicate values and are sure we don't have any_..... so reading all this.. you actually do have duplicates. You need to be certain about these things. Thie quickest why to find the offending rows is to turn of the constraint, load the data and inspect it in place.

Comment: @Jayvee: Thank you very much for your time and effort! We tried doing what you said. Could you please have a look at my initial question / post again? I added something all the way in the end, because I am not able to insert images here. Thank you very much, we really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the order_purchase_timestamp is defaulted to the wrong format in the connection manager:

[image]

and when taken by the read flat file task is leaving only the time downstream, you can enable data viewer to see it:

[image]

[image]

When that fields get converted to purchase_day in the derived column in the data conversion transformation it assumes the current date and hence the today's date you see and which also generates duplicate keys.

You may need to change the data type to db_dbtimestamp in the connection managers and all the transformations. Also, this issue will happen with other dates as well

For more information regarding SSIS and SQL Server data types:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Which data type should we use if we don't want to consider hours minutes and seconds, but simply just the date?

Comment: I would suggest to read it as is in origin, with time, using dt_dbtimestamp, and later on take only the date part, which I think is what you do in the data conversion to purchase day. Once you have the correct date/time from the beginning, this conversion should work fine

Comment: Thank you very much! We did that now and getting this error (it is the same, however the date is different):
Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_Fact_Sales'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Stg_Fact_Sales'. The duplicate key value is (2017-01-23, cb07b3df7c64648bbeceb85cacd464c9, 62c50c1af4dfdc4149d25c5222043d39, 8a0793d04e0f4be13434516ee7037104, 38321).".

Comment: We checked the data for this date and it does not contain duplicates...

Comment: Date looks good now, Could you please post the amended package? I'll have a look

Comment: @Rachel Actually, I had a look at the csvs and there are duplications, which makes sense as the same order may have many items. if you look on order items by the order id that gave you primary key violation you will see it has more than one line. You need to either aggregate the amount by order_id or include oder_item_id in fact sales.

Comment: Okay thank you! We are not really understanding why that is an issue.. Can you maybe explain again? Why do we need to include the order_item_id in fact sales? 

I know it's an unusual question, but do you maybe have time for a 15min online meeting to help us? We would really appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, I will show you the issue in another answer