# SSIS: Average transformation for duplicate entries

Tags: ssis

For a university group project, we are building a data warehouse using SQL Server Management and Visual Studio. We are currently in the staging area and want to fill the tables with data. All of our dimension tables work fine, one of our fact tables as well and right now we are trying to move forward with the Reviews fact table.

In this table we would like to show the average score (made for orders) for each customer unique id, taking into account the different dates. In other words, one customer can make more than one review on the same day, so we want to do the average for those cases. If the customer made the review on a different day, we do not want to include this information for the calculation of the average. Could you maybe help us how to do this with visual studio? We tried using the Aggregate function, but it did not work out.

Any help would be really much appreciated! (We don’t care about the relation with the order, we just want to know the average for the scores made by the same customers on the same day.)

For a better understanding and insight, we are providing you with our SQL scripts, flat files as well as visual studio data flow: [Download files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mh07ekp5Ld5wOcBIAY2LDAVb25wZNQ_t/view?usp=sharing) (You can ignore the option we have so far for the Reviews fact table, since we did the aggregation in the csv file "olist_order_reviews_dataset_NEW.csv" manually. However, we would really like to use the original csv file "olist_order_reviews_dataset.csv" in order to be able to make the transformation within the staging area.

All the best and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation looks fine, but there are data issues. As there is a free form entry field in the reviews (comments), this is causing issues when semicolons or line feeds are included in the comments:

[image]

Adding error handling of the offending rows is one option to solve the problem:

[image]

[image]

The other option would be to do a data cleanse on the review file before processing it.

**The semicolon and CRLF inside comments issues**

This happens because as the flat file that contains the review data is separated by semicolon ";" , when the comments, which are just free text entered by the customers contains a semicolon, it confuses the SSIS flat file connection making it interpret this as a separator and therefore the text that follows that semicolon as the next field and so forth. The same thing happens when there is CRLF inside these fields.
The good news is that the text comes qualified with double quotes ("), so the solution is to set the connection manager accordingly:

[image]

Please notice that I have set "Text Qualifier" to "

---

Still I would recommend to keep the error output to catch any issues with the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Could you maybe share your visual studio package with us, so we can see what exactly you did in the Aggregate as well as Multicast. We always faced the problem that we weren't able to do the mappings in the destination in the end, because we always lost the attributes due to the Aggregate function...

Comment: I haven't touched the aggregation. What other attribute do you need to come out of it?. Bear in mind that every attribute in the aggregation should either be part of the group by, or affected by an aggregation function (sum, count, max, etc.). The multicast is only a dummy transform to see what is coming out of the aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! We would just like to have the customer unique id, the creation date as well as average score.. so it would be correct to group by the customer unique id and by the date and then do the average for the score?

Comment: yes, that's correct, once you remove the bad data, you just need to include the DB destination instead of the multicast.

Comment: Thank you ver much, it worked for us now! Could you maybe give us a more detailed explanation of why we needed to do the error handling and remove so many rows?

Comment: Actually I had another look and found a solution to process those rows, as the text is qualified with double quotes. I've updated the answer, please see the section I added at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped! Works prefect now! Did you see I added another comment in the first question / post? Could you maybe have a look at that question? It would be really helpful for us.

Comment: I had a look and see that you already have a payment dimension. As the relation between order_items and payment is many-to-many you may need to take one of the two out of the fact table. It would make more sense to take payment out and add a new "bridge" table to link order_id with payment_id. If you find troubles implementing it please raise another question.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask for new questions to be raised but this is the way Stackoverflow works, the idea as that other people, not only the original poster, can also benefit from the answers. If we resolve the many-to-many relationship in the original question regarding a duplicate PK it would be "hidden" to anyone searching for help regarding linking tables with many-to-many relationship or similar.

Comment: I'm sorry about that and didn't know that since I'm new to the platform - but of course makes total sense! I created a new post / question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70596683/ssis-model-design-issue-causing-duplications-can-two-fact-tables-be-connected. If you could have a look at it, we would be more than happy! Thank you very much!